# Sending Word 2010 document as an attachment

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-word-2010

We have `Office 2010` installed. On most PCs, when one creates a document in Word and does a `File` → `Save & Send as e-mail attachment` it opens a new message in `Outlook 2010` and adds the document as an attachment.

However on some PC's it puts the document in the body of the new message, rather than adding it as an attachment.

This is not desired. How can that behaviour be changed?

Comment: You mean like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/sDQNP.png ?

Comment: Not quite: The normal and desired behaviour is that it adds the documents as regular attachments. It does, however, just insert the document's content as the message body, i.e. whatever was typed in Word ends up as readable text in the message body, not as an icon in the body (as you have made a screenshot of). (Pretty much as if one had typed directly in Outlook, rather than in Word.)